# Lookup Cell Value from Excel in Access and Return Data from Access

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a function to look up in an Access table a value from an Excel cell and to return a value from a column in the matched row in the Access table.

I am using the code below, but it just keeps returning #value even though I get an exact match in the Access db.

```
Dim adoCN As ADODB.Connection
Dim strSQL As String
Const DatabasePath As String = "\\aur\hobo_data\Corporate\Corporate\3DOCK2         
    \D_IMA\Teams\Data Architecture and Management\Projects\Payments Transformation\02 -  
    Documents\23 - Data Architecture Deliverables\11 - ODS & Data Mart Model\04 Fundtech  
    Data Provision\Payments Transformation.mdb"

'Function argument descriptions
'LookupFieldName - the field you wish to search
'LookupValue - the value in LookupFieldName you're searching for
'ReturnField - the matching field containing the value you wish to return

Public Function DBVLookUp(TableName As String, _
    LookUpFieldName As Long, _
    LookupValue As String, _
    ReturnField As String) As Variant

    Dim adoRS As ADODB.Recordset

    If adoCN Is Nothing Then SetUpConnection
    Set adoRS = New ADODB.Recordset
    strSQL = "SELECT [" & LookUpFieldName & "], [" & ReturnField & _
             "] FROM [" & TableName & _
             "] WHERE [" & LookUpFieldName & "]='" & LookupValue & "';"
    'If lookup value is a number, then remove the two
    adoRS.Open strSQL, adoCN, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
    If adoRS.BOF And adoRS.EOF Then
        DBVLookUp = "Value not Found"
    Else
        DBVLookUp = adoRS.Fields(ReturnField).Value
    End If
    adoRS.Close
End Function

Sub SetUpConnection()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set adoCN = New Connection
    adoCN.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" 'Change to 3.51 for Access 97
    adoCN.ConnectionString = DatabasePath
    adoCN.Open
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "An error occurred"
End Sub
```

Comment: When you debug whats the value in `adoRS.Fields(ReturnField).Value` ??

Comment: 1. where the code has adors.BOF AND adors.EOF debug shows =<operation is not allowed when object is closed>
2. DBVLookUp = adoRS.Fields(ReturnField).Value shows

<Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.>

But can't undertstand this as it does match

Also 

StrSelect = "SELECT [[NAB_XML_FIELD_PATH]], [[FIELD_LOGICAL_ID]]"
StrFrom = "FROM [[004-MINF Mapping to ISO]]"
StrWhere = "WHERE [[NAB_XML_FIELD_PATH]]='Document/FIToFICstmrDrctDbt/GrpHdr/MsgId';"

Comment: it's the column name that isn't found, there must be some difference in the name you are passing as a column name - why have you got **double square brackets []?**

Comment: I don't think the double brackets are making any difference, debugging the code seems to stop here

Comment: I don't think the double brackets are making any difference, debugging the code seems to stop here adoRS.Open strSQL, adoCN, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly.  The debug code shows for adoRS <Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.>.  So I believe the issue is that the connection statement > 
    If adoCN Is Nothing Then SetUpConnection
Is not opening the Access DB Connection